# Python validate_email not working in some domains

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp, email-validation

I'm working in a feature that validates an email address, ensuring the address exists, as part of a script in python. For this purpose I use a package called [`validate_email`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email).

The problem is that with some domains the validator seems to reject valid emails. For other domains works just fine, and I have no clue of what could be happening.

Here is my code:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
try:
    mx_ok = validate_email(email_name+"@"+domain,check_mx=True)
except:
    mx_ok = None

if mx_ok:
    try:
        exists = validate_email(email_name+'@'+domain,verify=True)
    except:
        exists = None
```

And some examples:

- marketing@palafoxhoteles.com #Exists and the validator accepts it. Non-existing addresses in this domain are correctly rejected
- reservas@hotelcadizplaza.com #Exists and the validator rejects it.

I know these rejected addresses actually exist because in an online email validation tool are correctly validated. I'm using http://www.mailtester.com/testmail.php to check the correctness of my script.

What could cause my script to reject some existing addresses that mailtester.com accepts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is more of a problem with the module. Try raising this issue on the GitHub repository where the module is located: https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues

Comment: I've created the issue in the repo: https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues/69, let's see if it's answered. Thanks!